# GET Request Flask

Tags: python, flask, get

I have written something that works, but I am 100% sure that there is an even more efficient and faster way of doing what I did.

The code that I have written, essentially uses OpenBayes' library and creates a network with its nodes, relationships between nodes, and the probabilities and distributions associated with each of the nodes. Now, I was creating a GET request using Flask, in order to process the conditional probabilities by simply sending the request.

I will send some evidence (given values), and set the node in which I want its probability (observed value). Mathematically it looks like this:

> **Observed Value = O** and **Evidence = En, where n > 1**
>
> P( O | E1, E2, ..., En)

My final goal would be to have a client/server ping the server hosting this code(with the right parameters) and constantly give me the final values of the observed probability, given the evidence (which could be 1 or more values). The code I have written so far for the GET request portion is:

```
@app.route('/evidence/evidence=<evidence>&observed=<obv>', methods=['GET'])

def get_evidence(evidence, obv):

    # Take <evidence> and <obv> split them up. For example:
    # 'cloudy1rain0sprinkler1' to 'cloudy1', 'rain0' and 'sprinkler1', all in a nice list.

    analyzeEvidence, observedNode = evidence.upper().strip(), obv.upper().strip()
    string, count, newCount, listOfEvidence =  "", 0, 0, {}
    counter = sum(character.isdigit() for character in analyzeEvidence)

    # This portion is to set up all the evidences.

    for y in xrange(0, counter):
        string, newCount = "", count
        for x in xrange(newCount, len(analyzeEvidence)):
            count += 1
            if analyzeEvidence[x].isalpha() == True:
                string += str(analyzeEvidence[x])
            elif analyzeEvidence[x].isdigit() == True and string in allNodes:
                if int(analyzeEvidence[x]) == 1 or int(analyzeEvidence[x]) == 0:
                    listOfEvidence[string] = int(analyzeEvidence[x])
                    break
                else: abort(400)
                break
            else: abort(400)

    net.SetObs(listOfEvidence) # This would set the evidence like this: {"CLOUDY": 1, "RAIN":0}


    # This portion is to set up one single observed value

    string = ""
    for x in xrange(0, len(observedNode)):
        if observedNode[x].isalpha() == True:
            string += str(observedNode[x])
            if string == "WETGRASS":
                string = "WET GRASS"
        elif observedNode[x].isdigit() == True and string in allNodes:
            if int(observedNode[x]) == 1 or int(observedNode[x]) == 0:
                observedValue = int(observedNode[x])
                observedNode = string
                break
            else: abort(400)
        else: abort(400)

    return str(net.Marginalise(observedNode)[observedValue]) # Output returned is the value like: 0.7452
```

Given my code, is there any way to optimize it? Also, Is there a better way of passing these parameters that doesn't take so many lines like my code does? I was planning on setting fixed key parameters, but because my number of evidence can change per request, I thought this would be one way in doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily split your evidence input into a list of strings with this:

```
import re

# 'cloudy1rain0sprinkler1' => ['cloudy1', 'rain0' and 'sprinkler1'].
evidence_dict = {}
input_evidence = 'cloudy1rain0sprinkler1'
# looks for a sequence of alphabets followed by any number of digits
evidence_list = re.findall('([a-z]+\d+)', input_evidence.lower())
for evidence in evidence_list:
    name, val, _ = re.split('(\d+)', evidence)
    if name in allNodes:
        evidence_dict[name] = val

# evidence_dict = {'cloudy': 1, 'rain': 0, 'sprinkler': 1}
```

You should be able to do something similar with the observations.

I would suggest you use an HTTP POST. That way you can send a JSON object which will already have the separation of variable names and values done for you, all you'll have to do is check that the variable names sent are valid in `allNodes`. It will also allow your variable list to grow somewhat arbitrarily.

Comment: Thanks, @junnytony! Yeah, I was thinking about using HTTP POST if we take security and the passing of parameters into account. For that, would it be better to use the 'request' or 'httplib2' library? Would have to do some reading on that in order to get thorough understanding.

Comment: I prefer the request library. It's more user friendly IMO